grub 2.12 compiled - grub-install gives error for encrypted boot or encrypted root with --boot-directory option
I have ubuntu 22.04 and grub compiled from git source 2.12. After grub is installed in separate directory, from there I executed grub-install with below command and it gives error for encrypted partition lvm.
/home/<userid>/grub/install# /home/<userid>/grub/install/sbin/grub-install -d /home/<userid>/grub/install/lib/grub/x86_64-efi  --bootloader-id=ubuntu1  --boot-directory=/home/<userid>/boot_crypt1 --efi-directory=/home/<userid>/boot_crypt1/efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
/home/<userid>/grub/install/sbin/grub-install: error: disk `lvm/boot_crypt1' not found.

boot_crypt1 is the encrypted boot. However, same error shows when used with unencrypted boot directory for encrypted root. I have encrypted root partition lvm/<nvme..>_crypt.
I believe 2.12 is stable grub and I used same git tag for source. In /etc/default/grub file below line is added:
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

Since it is separate grub compiled and installed, in install local directory I copied all contents from /etc/grub.d and /etc/grub. However, still same error for encrypted partition shows up.
What can be missing or what is the solution?
